# Kafka-Streams app unknown topic or partition error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a problem trying to get a Kafka-Streams running with a Kafka Cluster. As you can see from the bootstrap servers property there are 3 Kafka servers in the cluster. All is working fine there. But for some reason when this app is started I keep getting "unknown topic or partition error" errors as if the Stream app does not have rights to create the Changlog and Partition topics it needs to run. I have it Kafka set to "auto.create.topics.enable=true" but I ont think this is the issue. Any clues would be a great help.

```
#Docker YAML file

#KV STORE Instance
   kvstore1gcf102:
        image: kafka-kv-store:1.1.125
        restart: always
        hostname: kvstore_13_1_gcf102
        ports:
            - 7071:8080
        environment:
            APPLICATIONID_KVSTORE: "kafka-kv-store-gcf102"
            HOSTNAME_KVSTORE: "kvstore_13_1_gcf102"
            STREAMPROPS_KVSTORE: "bootstrap.servers=192.168.2.13:9092,192.168.2.14:9092,192.168.2.16:9092 num.standby.replicas=0"
          TOPIC_KVSTORE: "messages_shown"
```

Error I am getting:

```
18:31:11,637 WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher
- [Consumer clientId=kafka-kv-store-gcf102-ab44b41c-71cb-4cfa-926a-898cdfbb192c-StreamThread-1-consumer, 
groupId=kafka-kv-store-gcf102] Received unknown topic or partition error 
in ListOffset request for partition kafka-kv-store-gcf102-shown-count-kv-repartition-0
```

as an edit:

```
root@SRV-003:~/tmp# /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server 192.168.2.13:9092 | grep kafka-kv-store-gcf102
kafka-kv-store-gcf102-shown-count-kv-changelog
kafka-kv-store-gcf102-shown-count-kv-repartition
```

Comment: @OneCricketeer I placed in as edit on the question. I can't format it here.
I just checked it on a working K8s system and the same topics are created as you see above.

Comment: That seems fine, but are you sure your Docker Compose can connect to your k8s environment? Why use Compose instead of running pods in k8s, if that is working?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sorry let me clarify. I have two environments One a Docker environment and another K8s environment. the K8s Env works perfectly. The Docker Env is the one that has the issue. The two environments don't intersect in any way.

Comment: But they use the same bootstrap servers? If so, then the topics are the same, and you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: @OneCricketeer   No, no, no the two do not intersect at all. They just happened to be named the same as I am working to get k8s into production but it is months away from being implemented.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure why you said it's working on k8s. If it's a different cluster, then do you have the same configuration settings on both? Any ACLs or auth settings you're missing? Since you didn't share the Kafka config or Steams code, it's hard to reproduce your issue. Yes, the repartition topics should get automatically created, but not if auth is needed

Comment: `I have it Kafka set to "auto.create.topics.enable=true" but I ont think this is the issue.` --  It's highly discouraged to use this feature, and it's not required for Kafka Streams to work. Kafka Streams internally uses the `AdminClient` to issue "create topics" requests.